# Override back button with popup message

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation component to navigate between my fragments. I have 1 fragment where the user can edit some data. As soon as anything changes i set the flag "saved = false" and after user presses "save" button, flag goes to "saved = true". Now, what i want to do, is to add a usual popup message (Do u want to save the changes? Yes No Cancel) when the user pressed a back button, but did not save the changes. Also i want to add it to both buttons:

**This one**

[image]

**And this one**

[image]

I looked into this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back
and it works only for (main) back button, but not for the one on the toolbar. When i need to go to previous fragment in code i use:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

So do i need to somehow override this function or add a callback? Or maybe there is some entirely different (better) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time plz **share your code**.

I had the same problem and this is my solution, You need to override onOptionsItemSelected in your activity/fragment  and to check when "back" arrow is pressed.

**Code**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: 
        // put here what you would like to happen when u click on it
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** : I just notice that you are using Kotlin so i added a kotlin example:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
when (item.getItemId()){
    android.R.id.home -> {
        // put your code here
        return true
    }
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
```

}

Feel free to ask anything:)

Comment: hi, thank you. But it works only if put it in MainAktivity. In a Fragment it does nothing at all.

Comment: never mind. Fixed it. Your solution rocks, the only thing is to make sure that fragment has "setHasOptionsMenu(true)". After adding that - all good.